# Unable to connect React Native app to MySQL database using Node.js. (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306)

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, express, mysql-workbench

I am very new to programming so I do apologize if this is a really simple question.

So, I have been trying to connect my React Native application to the MySQL Database using Node and Express server, but I keep on getting the following error (I have checked other stackoverflow questions as well, but nothing has helped):

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPGit.png)

I have checked my host name and port number multiple times and the all the information seems to be correct. I am not sure what is wrong with the following code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var mysql = require("mysql");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { application } = require("express");

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1', // Your connection adress (localhost).
  port: "3306",
  user: "root", // Your database's username.
  password: "", // Your database's password.
  database: "birthdays", // Your database's name.
});

connection.connect(function (error) {
  if (error) console.log(error);
  else console.log("connected");
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(4547, () => {
  console.log("Go to http://localhost:4547/dinners so you can see the data.");
});


app.get("/users", function (req, res) {
  con.query("select * from users", function (error, rows, fields) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    else {
      console.log(rows);
      res.send(rows);
    }
  });
});
```

I run this code by typing "node fileName.js" in the terminal.

I don't know if this is helpful, but I have also connected by MySQL database to MySQL Workbench.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is your MySQL server up and running? Is it configured to accept TCP connections on port 3306?

Comment: I think it should be since I used this same information to connect the database to MySQL workbench.

Comment: So workbench literally connects to `127.0.0.1` (not `localhost`) on port 3306? What sort of _terminal_ are you running your Express app in? Are you using any containers (Docker, WSL) or virtualisation?

Comment: Just to clarify, I actually used "localhost" for MySQL Hostname and "3306" as MySQL server port while making the connection to MySQL Workbench along with SSH information corresponding to my Ubuntu server (I have tried "localhost" in the above code as well, that was not working either). I am not really using Express in any direct way. I just installed it based on this other tutorial I had seen. I am not even sure about what it does. And no I am not familiar with the other things you have mentioned either. :( I just run "node fileName.js in my React Native project terminal)

Comment: What's this about an Ubuntu server and SSH? Is your MySQL server on the same machine as you're running Express? Because that's what `localhost` means

Comment: So I first created Ubuntu server on DigitalOcean droplet and then I followed the instructions here to install MySQL: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04 . SSH is what I use to log onto my ubuntu server using my terminal and then I used the "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" connection method on MySQL Workbench to connect my database to it. Then I installed express and node using terminal (npm install express, npm install node I think), and now I have been basically running the above code using the node command. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: And yes they are on the same machine.

Comment: Are you running Express on the Ubuntu server as well or on your own computer? `/Users/harleen/Desktop` doesn't look like a server filesystem path

Comment: Ohh, I installed Express by just using React Native project's terminal. Sorry I thought this would mean they are still on the same machine, but this might be the issue. Would you recommend I install Express and Node.js both on ubuntu server as well and then run this code?

Comment: That would probably get you unblocked but you'd then have to make any API calls from React to your Ubuntu server address

Comment: Oh I see. Seems like this is going to be a little bit of work. Thank so much. I really appreciate your help Phil.